# How to check the value is in object with Chai?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, object, assertions, chai

Is it possible to test the value is contained within certain array with Chai assertion library?

Example:

```
var myObject = {
    a : 1,
    b : 2,
    c : 3
};
var myValue = 2;
```

I need to do something like this (however it is not working):

```
expect(myObject).values.to.contain(myValue);
//Error: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined

expect(myObject).to.contain(myValue);
//Error: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'
```

How can I test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [chai fuzzy plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-fuzzy) has the functionality you needed.

```
var myObject = {
    a : 1,
    b : 2,
    c : 3
};
var myValue = 2;
myObject.should.containOneLike(myValue);
```

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively if you want to check the value along with the property you can do

```
expect(myObject).to.have.property('b', myValue);
```

You won't need the plugin for this check.

Answer (score 2):

if the object is bit nested, like

```
{
    "errors": {
        "text": {
            "message": "Path `text` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "text",
                "value": ""
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "text",
            "value": "",
            "$isValidatorError": true
        }
    },
    "_message": "todos validation failed",
    "message": "todos validation failed: text: Path `text` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

then do an assertion on errors.text.message, we can do like

> expect(res.body).to.have
>             .property('errors')
>             .property('text')
>             .property('message', 'Path `text` is required.');

Comment: In that case it's much better to use .nested, like so: expect({a: {b: ['x', 'y']}}).to.have.nested.property('a.b[1]');